# Boost.Asio: The difference between async_read and async_receive

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

What's the difference between [async_read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) and [async_receive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_receive/overload2.html)?

Comment: They do different things. One just reads, the other reads a particular amount or errors. See the very pages you linked - they'll tell you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`async_receive` is a function that just receives into a buffer, but may not receive the amount you asked for. (It'll be equal or less, never more.)

`async_read`, however, will always receive the amount you asked for, as it states:

> This function is used to asynchronously read a certain number of bytes of data from a stream. The function call always returns immediately. The asynchronous operation will continue until one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The supplied buffers are full. That is, the bytes transferred is equal to the sum of the buffer sizes.
> - An error occurred.

The only thing the page is a bit vague on is what `async_read` does if it doesn't get that many bytes, and the connection closes gracefully. (Does that count as "error"?) This can probably be determined with a quick test. (`async_receive`, however, would just give you what it got.)

Comment: In response to my own question: If async_read doesn't get the number of bytes because the stream closed gracefully before the requested size was obtained, the read handler gets invoked with an error of boost::asio::error::eof.

Answer (score 1):

The first is a free function, the second is a member function.

Another difference is `socket_base::message_flags flags` parameter. See possible values, for example, in the [`recv(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) manual page.

#### Edit:

With `async_receive` you need to check how many bytes you got. Use it if you want to read *at max N bytes*, vs. *exactly N bytes*  with `async_read`. Sorry, thought that was sort of obvious from boost docs.

Comment: When would I use one over the other?

Comment: "Consider using the async_read function if you need to ensure that the requested amount of data is received before the asynchronous operation completes."

Comment: So does that mean if I use async_recieve, I might not get all my data, but the error flag will say everything's fine? I'm not really sure what that line means.

Comment: From async_recieve's link: "The receive operation may not receive all of the requested number of bytes." So, yes. Network stuff typically works this way: You might not get everything you asked for (the other side didn't send it, it's still in transit, etc.) async_read is a convenience function that will keep trying for you, if you know you want X bytes.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Mind putting that in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yes, with `async_receive` you need to check how many bytes you got. Use it if you want to read *at max N bytes*, vs. *exactly N bytes* (`async_read`).