# async_read doesn't read data sent from telnet

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

This is my current code for the server. I connect to the server using telnet.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class Connection
{
public:
    Connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : socket_(io_service)
    {

    }

    void start()
    {
        AsyncRead();
    }

    tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return socket_;
    }
private:
    void AsyncRead()
    {
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                                [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
                                {
                                    if (!ec)
                                    {
                                        std::cout << data_ << std::endl;
                                    }
                                });
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 1024 };
    char data_[max_length];
};


class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
        acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        start_accept();
    }

private:
    void start_accept()
    {
        Connection* connection = new Connection(io_service_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(connection->socket(), [this, connection](boost::system::error_code ec)
                               {
                                   //std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                   if(!ec)
                                   {
                                       std::cout << "Connected." << std::endl;
                                       connection->start();
                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                       delete connection;
                                   }

                                   start_accept();
                               });
    }

    boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        server s(io_service, 7899);

        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of `async_read` I use `async_read_some` I can get the first message sent from telnet and thats it.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async_read` will read the number of bytes specified in the length parameter. You aren't seeing the first message because `async_read` is still waiting to read `max_length` bytes. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982514/boost-asio-the-difference-between-async-read-and-async-recieve) discusses similar behaviour

Comment: How do I proceed here, if async_read waits for max_length bytes and I just want to sent lets say 3 bytes and than 5, and then 10, how can I print all the messages sent from telnet, one by one and not wait for max_length ?

Comment: @vBx: The most direct method is to use the [tcp::socket::async_read_some()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html) method, which calls the handler as the data arrives.  As an alternative, you can use [async_read_until()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html), which will call the handler when a delimiter or size is reached.

Comment: @DaveS: I tried using the async_read_some method, and this one just prints the first message I sent. So if I type "hello" from telnet, I get the message in my server, if I type again "world" this doesn't get printed and all the other messages I write don't get printed. So just the first one.

Comment: You need to re-register your handler, once the handler is activated, it must be queued into the io_service again, just call AsyncRead() again from within the lambda

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. One more question I have. I see some incorrect output when I use a "," in my messages. Like this: sent "hello, world" which get printed and then if I send "baw" I get "baw" and on a new line I get ", world". Do you know why is this happening ?

Comment: Not sure, this could be a feature of the telnet client, try using netcat to see if the issue persists, like so: `echo "This is, a test" | netcat localhost 7899` (assuming your using Linux, if not you'll have to download netcat for windows)